# how to receive text directly from server in TCP/IP messaging without click a button in C#?

Tags: c#, tcp, messaging

I have made an WPF application client for receiving text via TCP/IP messaging in C#. But i must click button2 to receive the data from server. I want to ask how to make like a chat application where the text is received directly without click button2 ?
My code is just like below :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text="Client Started";
        clientSocket.Connect("10.228.183.81", 5000);
        textBox2.Text = "Client Socket Program - Server Connected ...";

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            textBox2.Text = returndata;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Add a timer and perform your operation at a set interval

Comment: Yep you could implement a timer with the onTick or elasped event handler code being your button 2 click function code and each time the timer would ticket it would connect and check for recieved data.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your application threaded.
So everything you receive should be handled by a thread.

You can have a look at a pretty good [sample here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12893/TCP-IP-Chat-Application-Using-C)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a timer object like so to check based on a interval provided.  Then you could Use Task Factory to keep it from locking up your UI thread and update the TextBox with received data via a delegate (Mine is a simple probably not how you would most likely want to implement it, just giving an idea for example purposes).

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();

//On application startup start your timer like so
myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
// checks every 5 seconds, Interval accepts double in milliseconds
myTimer.Interval = 5000;
myTimer.Start();

// Then create a event handler for your timer Tick event
private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs) {
    // stop your timer and restart it possibly once you received data and have updated gui
    // using task will keep it from Locking UI thread
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    { 
        //perform check to socket and update UI using some type of delegate like below
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
              TextBox.Append(Recieved Text From Socket); // runs on UI thread
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent glad it helps, if you could please mark it as the answer!